# Hide contact types from WordPress cms users

Tags: wordpress, permissions, acl, admin

I am checking the CMS permissions on my CiviCRM installation on Wordpres. I have three types of CiviCRM users:

1. Administrator
2. Author
3. Publisher

In CiviCRM I have two types of contacts:

A) Donors
B) Beneficiaries

We need to hide the donors (A) for the Editors and Authors users (2 and 3) and that they can see only the Beneficiaries (B).

We have disabled all Donor display permissions in [WordPress Permissions and access control](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/#:%7E:text=Access%20Control%20(Permissions)%20in%20WordPress,predefined%20User%20Roles%20from%20WordPress.), however this does not work.

The ACL permissions don't get us on the right track because there are only options to **"Show"** and **not "Hide"**.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think if you read more about the ACL you should find it can resolve your requirement, you just have to reverse your thinking, so the Group who you want to give limited access to do NOT get given 'Access all Contacts' (or whatever the wording in the Permission is) therefore they ONLY get access to the contacts that the ACL specifies

Comment: also your Question uses different terminology for 2 and 3, in one place you call them  Author and Publisher, later you refer to Editors and Authors.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Thanks, I wasn't clear on my ideas, but this worked for me. Could you post your answer to give yourself credit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think ACLs should be able to resolve your requirement, you just have to reverse your thinking, so the Group who you want to give limited access to do NOT get given 'Access all Contacts' (or whatever the wording in the Permission is) therefore they ONLY get access to the contacts that the ACL specifies